# Woher kommt die Bedeutung "etwas verraten" von "durchstechen"

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Heute morgen begegnete mir im *Tagesspiegel* (es geht um das Leaking des Terminkalenders des US-Präsidenten) folgender Text:

> Das Weiße Haus versucht Medienberichten zufolge herauszufinden, wer den Kalender an "Axios" durchgestochen hat.

Ich war zunächst ein bisschen verblüfft über die Formulierung, weil mir "durchstechen" im Sinne von "verraten" oder "weitergeben" absolut unbekannt war - Der Duden hat allerdings einen [Eintrag](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/durchstechen_stechen_durchbohren) dazu, viele andere Wörterbücher scheinen diese Bedeutung nicht zu kennen, auch der Grimm nicht.

Woher kommt diese Bedeutung? Ich kann mir auch bildlich nicht vorstellen, was sie meint - Einen Eimer durchzustechen führt zwar dazu, dass er leckt (siehe engl. "leak"), aber dann müsste das Behältnis und nicht das Auslaufende Objekt des Satzes sein.

Ist diese Bedeutung wirklich gängiger, als ich meine?

Comment: Für mich war das von jeher eine unbedachte Formulierung. Klingt oberflächlich chique, ist aber inhaltsquer; will sagen: Beim genaueren Drübernachdenken kommt man zum Schluss, dass man so nicht reden sollte; etwa wie bei dem in männerdominierten Business-Kreisen so beliebten *die Hose runterlassen*.

Comment: Das ist eine sehr verbreitete Formulierung. " Beim genaueren Drübernachdenken kommt man zum Schluss, dass man so nicht reden sollte;" ist eine völlig subjektive und unbegründete Meinung.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Wenn diese Formulierung so weit verbreitet wäre, gehe ich davon aus, dass ich sie in den letzten 50 Jahren schonmal gelesen hätte. Mit dem zweiten Teil deines Kommentars bin ich ohne weitere Begründung von Christian aber einig.

Comment: Ohne die Historie zu kennen vermute ich, dass es Umschläge mit Informationen sind, die unter Türen durchgesteckt werden. Belege dafür habe ich aber keine.

Comment: @userunknown   Das ist immerhin eine hübsche Erklärung, auch wenn sie vielleicht nur gut ausgedacht ist.

Comment: @userunknown Gefällt mir auch. (Auch wenn ich's nicht glaube)

Comment: @user-unknown *jemandem etwas stecken* ist recht allgemein. Ob das hierher gehort, dafür fehlen Belege, müsste doch recht alt sein oder wie soll stecken zu stechen werden? English *to stick it to someone* "es jemandem (mal so richtig) geben, die Meinung geigen", und *jemandem etwas anheften* ist ja nah dran, aber doch unterschiedlich.

Comment: @tofro Dann liest du offenbar nicht allzuviel Tageszeitung. Hab nur mal ein paar Beispiele von spiegel.de, bemerkenswert dass dort Anführungszeichen gesetzt werden. Das spricht dafür, dass das Wort noch neu ist: http://www.spiegel.de/forum/politik/us-pressefreiheit-journalisten-beklagen-klima-der-angst-unter-obama-thread-102911-4.html, http://www.spiegel.de/forum/politik/geheimnisverrat-geplante-anzeige-gegen-whistleblower-empoert-abgeordnete-thread-198052-1.html, http://www.spiegel.de/forum/politik/mauscheleien-nrw-afd-verteilt-posten-schon-vor-der-wahl-thread-538602-7.html, ...

Comment: ... http://www.spiegel.de/forum/kultur/ard-laesterei-ueber-gottschalk-dead-man-talking-thread-55738-4.html, http://www.spiegel.de/forum/politik/spd-chef-schulz-ueber-union-wer-falschmeldungen-umlauf-setzt-zerstoert-vertrauen-thread-684580-1.html, http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-151666885.html

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Vielleicht sollte ich den Spiegel lesen (oder vielleicht auch nicht...)

Comment: Ich lese den Spiegel auch nicht. Ich bin mir sicher, dass in google _site: faz.de durchstechen_ oder _site: zeit.de durchstechen_ ähnlich schnell zu zahlreichen Resultaten führen würde.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach auf zeit.de: 1 Fundstelle, FAZ.de keine. Praktisch alle deine spiegel.de-Fundstellen sind in Kommentaren zu Artikeln. Da steht aber auch so soviel Unsinn drin, dass ich die nicht so recht als Referenzen akzeptieren will.

Comment: Ich werfe dann noch die Hypothese in den Raum, dass das ein missglückter Eindeutschungsversuch von *lancieren* ist. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/lancieren) sagt unter (c) immerhin, dass Lanze vom gleichen Wortstamm herrührt, da ist *durchstechen* schon ziemlich dicht dran.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Durchstechen, im Sinn von: vertrauliche Informationen, Interna, Geheimnisse (an die Öffentlichkeit, die Presse o. Ä.) verraten, heimlich weitergeben ([dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/durchstechen)) ist ein Mitte der [1990er](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=durchstechen;corpus=public;format=full;p=5;sort=date_desc;limit=50)-Jahre aufgekommener Neologismus, der zunächst im Journalistendeutsch aufgekommen ist.

Ähnlich wie ein Deich der das Wasser vom Land fernhält und der durchstochen werden kann ist es

> Ein schöner bildlicher Begriff, wenn über eine undichte Stelle in einer Behörde oder einem Unternehmen Vertrauliches an die Medien gelangt. „Durchstechen“ meint das gezielte Weitergeben von Informationen durch Insider – oft, um ein bestimmtes Thema in die Presse zu bringen.

[Quelle](https://medienpraxis.blog/2012/04/23/journalistendeutsch-teil-7/)

Eine Information durchstechen wurde vermutlich als Versuch eingeführt Worte, wie das englische "Leak", für das es keine sinngemäße deutsche Übersetzung gab, begreiflich zu machen.

[Quelle](https://books.google.de/books?id=tFR4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=Neologismus%20durchstechen&source=bl&ots=qt6_82Cb8u&sig=ACfU3U00ckoMaX1TXIuQFXVWWDGpGj_aFg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwieuoir4LjgAhUJY1AKHXfGDEUQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Neologismus%20durchstechen&f=false)

Des weiteren entspricht es sinngemäß Worbildungen wie eine "Information sickert durch" bringt aber eine sprachliche Gewalt mit, da das durchstechen von Informationen meist gewollt ist und eine Absicht darstellt jemandem oder eine Institution/Firma potentiell zu schaden/Geheimnisse öffentlich zu machen. So wie man den angesprochenen Deich durchstößt um das Wasser durchfließen zu lassen oder ein Messer, bzw weniger brutal eine Nadel durch eine Barriere stößt, so dass diese nicht mehr dicht ist.

Comment: Was spricht denn gegen "Leck" als Übersetzung für "Leak"? Im Englischen ist es doch auch eine Metapher.

Comment: @userunknown Tja gute Frage. Schließlich gibt es auch das Datenleck. Ich spekuliere, dass ein Leck im deutschen mehr ein unkontrolliertes, ungewolltes Ausströmen von Informationen ausdrücken würde. Der Leak an sich ist traditionell eine "zielgerichtete Enthüllung von vertraulichen Informationen eines Insiders". Alternativ könnte man auch vermuten, dass "Eine Information wurde geleckt" einfach dämlich klingt :D

Comment: @mtwde  Ja, *eine Information wurde geleckt* geht offenbar nicht gut. Aber man könnte doch sagen *eine Information wurde rausgelassen*.

Comment: @Christian: das klingt aber lange nicht so gut wie "to leak information" klingt. Da klingt "durchstechen" schon wesentlich lebendiger.

Comment: Danke für den Link auf dwds mit den Fundstellen. Bei der einzigen in der angefragten Bedeutung unter vielen anderen steht (BZ, 18.12.1996) *durchstochen* auch noch in Anführungszeichen... Der Verfasser scheint sich anscheinend auch nicht so sicher gewesen zu sein.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Für mich als chronisch altmodischem Erstsprachler klingt "durchstechen" eher verkrampft-möchtegernlebendig. Was mir fehlt, ist der klare bildliche Bezug. "Durchstechen" tut so, als wäre es eine Metapher (wie "to leak", was ja klar aus Bootsbau oder Kesselmacherei kommt), aber es ist keine. Das Bild ist kein Bild. Es sagt nichts, oder jedenfalls nur etwas recht Abstraktes ohne echten Sitz im Leben. "Durchstechen" wird überhaupt **nur** in Verbindung mit "Informationen" verwendet. Genau das ist ja der Kern der Eingangsfrage.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  PS: Übrigens, ein gutes deutsches Wort ist ***durchsickern***. *Eine Information ist durchgesickert.* Nun wird dabei natürlich kein Akteur genannt. Aber bei der häufigsten Verwendung von *durchstechen*, nämlich "*eine Information wurde durchgestochen*" ja auch nicht. Ich würde darum dem guten, alten *durchsickern* den Vorzug geben.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: '"Durchstechen" wird überhaupt **nur** in Verbindung mit "Informationen" verwendet.' - zumindest außerhalb der Umgangssprache und mit betontem "durch".

Comment: @>Christian: ja, auch nicht schlecht, aber Info sickert durch oder **wird** durchgestochen.

Answer (score 4):

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/durchstechen) kennt diese Bedeutung als

> vertrauliche Informationen, Interna, Geheimnisse (an die Öffentlichkeit, die Presse o. Ä.) verraten, heimlich weitergeben
>   vergleiche Durchstecherei (Lesart 2)

Auch im Grimmschen Wörterbuch taucht es auf, hier ein Auszug

> intransitiv, selten transitiv, mit einem oder mehreren heimliche betrügereien ausüben, meist zum schaden des gemeinen besten, heimliche anschläge schmieden, unter einer decke stecken Heynatz Antib. 1, 316. sie haben die sache mit einander durchgestochen abgekartet. sie stechen mit einander durch, stecken bei dem betrug unter einer decke. obwol die leute sich dessen (dasz der metzger ein unrichtiges gewicht angab) etzlich mal beschwerten, so hatte er doch daselbst mit dem markmeister und andern so darauf sehen sollten so durchgestochen dasz ihm nichts widerfuhr Herzog Julius v. Braunschw. 738. [...]

(durchstechen bis durchstelzen (Bd. 2, Sp. 1690 bis 1692))

Eine Verbreitung des Wortes Durchstecherei [kann auf Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Durchstecherei&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDurchstecherei%3B%2Cc0) eingesehen werden:[image: Verbreitung des Wortes Durchstecherei]

Die Verbreitete Nutzung scheint etwa um 1820 zu sein. Eine Suche nach den Wörtern durchstechen und durchgestochen zeigt einen sinkenden Verlauf von 1800 - heute. Da diese Worte aber auch in anderem Kontext verwendet werden, habe ich hier kein Bild eingefügt.

Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass es vom Dolch-/Messerstoß durch den Rücken oder die Brust kommt, vgl. auch jemandem ein Messer in den Rücken rammen. Dazu habe ich allerdings keine Quellen gefunden.

Comment: Oder vom Nähen? Wenn man einen Faden durch mehrere Lagen Stoff "durchsticht" gibt man den Faden (= Information) auch immer weiter.

Comment: Das Grimm'sche *durchstechen* wird aber mit einer doch recht anderen Bedeutung präsentiert, und nicht als *verraten* wie in der (chronisch von amerikanischen Gepflogenheiten gebeutelten) neudeutschen Journalismussprache.

Comment: Die Bedeutung von Durchstecherei im Sinne der Fragestellung kommt m.E. erst ab Mitte der 90er Jahre auf. Verwendung davor ist die "Betrügerei (im Amt)". Das Durchstechen von Informationen ist aber eher kein Betrug, daher sehe da zwar Wortgleichheit, aber nicht unbedingt selben Ursprung. Eher wie @IQV es andeutet